# How to insert record which has foregin key referenced to primary key of another table in PHP Script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

Here is my code-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "placement") 
    or die("Failed to connect MySQL: " . mysqli_error()); // Connecting to MySQL Database

    // Variable Declaration
    $StateName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["txtStateName"]);
    $Description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["txtDescription"]);
    $CountryName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["selectCountryName"]);
    $CountryId = "SELECT CountryId FROM tbl_country_master WHERE CountryName='$CountryName'";

    // Insert Query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_state_master(StateName, Description, CountryId) VALUES ('$StateName', '$Description', '$CountryId')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: frmAddState.php?msg=1");
    }

    mysqli_close($con);?>
```

CountryId in tbl_state_master is a foreign key and it is referenced to primary key of tbl_country_master. I'm not able to insert data as I'm getting error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: your CountryID input should be in a `<select>`.... we usually query all records from CountryTable then loop the result on that `<select>`.. by giving the `select value="CountryID"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never executed the query that's supposed to return the country ID. You just set `$CountryId` to the SQL string. It should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT CountryId FROM tbl_country_master WHERE CountryName='$CountryName'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    $CountryId = $row['CountryId'];
}
```

But ou don't need two separate queries, do it in just one:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_state_master(StateName, Description, CountryId)
        SELECT '$StateName', '$Description', CountryId
        FROM tbl_country_master WHERE CountryName='$CountryName'";
```

Comment: Ohh! Got it now! Now the code is working fine. Thank you! :)